# how can I prove that the real valued functions on hyperconnected spaces are constant?

Tags: general-topology

How can I prove that the every continuous real valued function on a hyperconnected space is constant?
A space is hyperconnected if the closure of open set is the entire space.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let $X$ be a hyperconnected space, and $f:X \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ a continuous map. Assume $f$ is not constant. Then there are points $x, y \in f(X)$, with $x \neq y$. In particular, we can find disjoint open intervals $U, V$ in $\mathbb{R}$ with $x \in U, y \in V$. Then $f^{-1}(U), f^{-1}(V)$ are open (by continuity of $f$), nonempty and disjoint. But then $X \smallsetminus f^{-1}(U)$ is closed and contains the non-empty open set $f^{-1}(V)$, so $X \smallsetminus f^{-1}(U)$ must contain the closure of $f^{-1}(V)$, as the closure of $f^{-1}(V)$ is the smallest closed subset of $X$ containing $f^{-1}(V)$. So $X=X \smallsetminus f^{-1}(U)$, which contradicts $f^{-1}(U)$ nomempty. $\square$

Answer (score 2):

It is easy to check that the image of a hyperconnected space under a continuous map is hyperconnected. It is also easy to check that the only hyperconnected subsets of a Hausdorff space are singletons.